# Subquery returning unwanted rows

Tags: sql, subquery

| e_id | name | d_id | salary | commission |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | John | 10 | 3000 | 200 |
| 20 | Jeremiah | 20 | 3000 | 400 |
| 30 | Jane | 10 | 3000 | 0 |
| 40 | James | 10 | 4000 | 500 |

I wanted to display employees that have the same d_id and salary with employees that have commission.

I tried:

```
SELECT name, d_id, salary
FROM employees
WHERE (d_id, salary) IN (
    SELECT d_id, salary
    FROM employees
    WHERE commission > 0);
```

Expected output:

| name | d_id | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 10 | 3000 |
| Jane | 10 | 3000 |

Actual output:

| name | d_id | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | 10 | 3000 |
| Jeremiah | 20 | 3000 |
| Jane | 10 | 3000 |
| James | 10 | 4000 |

Comment: the condition iisn't enough why those two,

Answer (score 1):

Modify your query as the following:

```
SELECT name, d_id, salary
FROM employees
WHERE (d_id, salary) IN (
    SELECT d_id, salary
    FROM employees
    Group By d_id, salary
    Having Max(commission) > 0 And Count(*) > 1);
```

`Having Max(commission) > 0` ensures that at least one employee have a commision value > 0.

`Count(*) > 1` ensures that there is more than one employee with the same d_id, salary.

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/2bS_DOkH).

Answer (score 0):

If your DBMS allows for window functions, you can use the `COUNT` one with partition on pairs of "*<d_id, salary>*". This will allow you to count how many existing identical couples are there for each couple. All count values bigger than 1 are the ones you're looking for.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(name) OVER(PARTITION BY d_id, salary) AS cnt 
    FROM tab
)
SELECT name, d_id, salary
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1
```

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3hXuGGUb5CTYP38U91job5/2)'s a demo for MySQL 8.0, but *most likely* will work on most DBMS' supporting window functions.